# How to add a one time payment?

Tags: magento2.3.3

We are looking to find out if anyone has done this before. We are looking for a way we can have a one time payment. We have customisation on our products and want to add a fee if it is someone's first time uploading there logo then there would be a charge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more information.

Is the logo associated with a customer, a quote or a quote item? If you have a customer ID or emailaddress you could search order repository to search for previous orders and dispatch a custom event to add (or remove) the fee. The fine folks at Inchoo wrote a nice howto. See: https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-magento-events-customer-first-order/

HTH, Tom